# How to read meta data from html with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I got an R script from a colleague but it is not entirely working. Its intention is to read a price for a product from a website.
the code is as follows:

```
vec_tectake <- try(paste0('https://www.tectake.ch/de/',j)%>%
                      read_html %>%
                      html_nodes('[itemprop="price"]') %>%
                      html_attr('content'))
```

to give an example of a full link, "j" could be "rudergerat-mit-trainingscomputer-401074"

After running the code, the vec_tectake i get is emtpy.
Now i'm not really sure why, as it has worked with the same code on another webpage. Could it be that it is because the price is marked as "meta content"?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the price is in own `<span>` tag, not within attributes:

```r
library(rvest)
j <- "rudergerat-mit-trainingscomputer-401074"
  read_html(paste0('https://www.tectake.ch/de/',j)) |>
    html_nodes(".price") |>
    html_text()
#> [1] "CHF 256.00"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Uff, that was fast.
Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.